# too many dml rows: 10001 when calling batch apex from Trigger

Tags: trigger, batch, dmlexception, limitexception

I am calling a batch class from trigger after update.
Eg: `database.executeBatch(new myTestBatch(trigger.newMap.keySet()),200);`

But it gives Too many dml rows:10001.

This is my batch class.

```
global class myTestBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public static boolean firstRun = true; 
    Set<Id> newPriceBookIds = new Set<Id>();

    global myTestBatch (Set<Id> newPriceBookIdsTrigger) {
        newPriceBookIds = newPriceBookIdsTrigger;
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Status__c,Booking_Queue__c,Description FROM Pricebook2 WHERE ID IN:newPriceBookIds]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Pricebook2> listpriceBooks) {
        List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = new List<Pricebook2>();
        Set<String> queueCodes =  new Set<String>();
        Set<String> descriptions =  new Set<String>();
        
        for(Pricebook2 priceBook : listpriceBooks){
            if( priceBook.Status__c != null && priceBook.Status__c == 'Send EDM'){
                queueCodes.add(priceBook.Booking_Queue__c);
                descriptions.add(priceBook.Description);
            }
        }
        
        List<SC_OPS_FD> fds = new List<SC_OPS_FD>();
        for(SC_OPS_FD fd : [SELECT Id,SC_OPS_Status__c FROM fd WHERE SC_OPS_Schedule_Change__c != 'Adhoc' AND SC_OPS_QueueCode__c IN : queueCodes AND
                            SC_OPS_Schedule_Change__c IN : descriptions AND ( SC_OPS_Status__c = 'New' OR SC_OPS_Status__c = 'Call Out') ]){
                               fd.SC_OPS_Status__c = 'Send Email';
                               fds.add(fd);  
                                                     
        }
        
        if(fds.size()>0){
            Database.update(fds, false);
        }
        
        firstRun = false;
        
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
       
    }
```

Is there are any solution for this scenario.

Thank you,
Thiru

Comment: Can you post the code of batch class?

Comment: Hi  @amitghadage
Question updated with batch class code

Comment: Why don't you just reduce the batch size?

Comment: @NickCook that's not the good approach as 1 parent can also have 10000+ child records.

Comment: I tried to reduce it to 100.
But it was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking id of parent record. You can pass
Set queueCodes,Set descriptions in your batch constructor from trigger.

And in start query do query on child records(SC_OPS_FD) and update in execute. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @prajjwal agrawal.
I have 11000 child records . So it will give the same error even if I query on child records know?

Comment: So you mean the query in start method gives the error?
My query in execute method also have 11000 records

Comment: No the problem is you are getting lots of data to update at once. There is 10000 dml row limit.

Query have limit of 50000(batch have extra limit) record. So query child record in start so that it will update record in chunks i.e 200 at a time. Instead of 11000 at once.

Comment: Got it. I will try this and let you know. Thank you so much

Comment: You need not to do query on Parent as you only need queue id and description. Create those set in trigger to avoid that query. Just do child query in start that you are doing in execute.

Comment: yes, understood

Comment: This is working.
Thank you so much!!